# How to use a script library across modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use a 3rd party library "emailjs.com" in a react project i'm working on (uses webpack to bundle the modules).

The issue i'm having is that I need to initialise the library in the html like so

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.emailjs.com/dist/email.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   (function(){
      emailjs.init("YOUR USER ID");
   })();
</script>
```

https://www.emailjs.com/docs/api-reference/emailjs-send/

Now I need to call the library in my react component on button click

```
  _submitForm(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Button Click works"); // This is printed fine

    // Undefined
    emailjs.send("my_service","my_template",{
      name: "James",
      notes: "Check this out!"
    });
  }
```

However I get an emailJS is undefined error (as I expected). My question is what the correct way to give my "form" component scope of the emailJS module.

I've tried creating "emailjs.js"

```
export default () => {
   // Minified email code in here
}
```

Then importing it like so

```
import emailjs from '../PathToComponent/emailjs';
```

However this is failing to compile, i'm getting the error "Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'vertx'", however all dependencies should be contained inside the emailJS minified file?

If anyone has any suggestions or perhaps a better way to send my e-mails from within a react componenet please let me know!

Form component: http://pastebin.com/x5KVPKXm
emailJS Export: http://pastebin.com/NA40ZrTT

Comment: do you use webpack? Try get `emailjs` from `window` - `window.emailjs.send`

Comment: You should configure the module bundler you use to know how to treat emailjs

Comment: Yes I use webpack sorry updated post to reflect that, Wow never knew it would be this simple thanks so much! Is this good practice to invoke functions from the window?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meteor + React + Highchart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35163499/meteor-react-highchart)